# Why does this rollback function not work as expected

Tags: python, python-db-api

I am going to execute 2 sql queries and I want to put them in a transaction, if any query failed then call `rollback()`. The code is shown as following and 2 queries are

`str_trunction`: truncate the table &
`str_insert`: insert some rows

codes:

```
try:
        mydb.start_transaction(consistent_snapshot=False,
                               isolation_level=None,
                               readonly=None)
        mycursor.execute(str_truncate)
        mycursor.executemany(str_insert+'ssss', [data[i].values() for i in range(len(data))])
        raise Exception
        mycursor.commit()

except Exception, e:
        mydb.rollback()
        print("Error captured, rollback. \n %s" % e[0])

finally:
        mycursor.close()
        mydb.close()
```

As shown, I use `+'ssss'` to create an exception, when I execute the code, the Exception str `Error captured ...` is shown as expected, which means the function `rollback()` should be executed. However, my table is still truncated. Why could this happen?

Comment: Where are you *starting* your commit? If you don't start a commit, then you end up in autocommit mode by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After try statement add this line

```
mydb.autocommit = false
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and this works! But I just tried the `start_transaction` function (as shwon in main post) to start transaction manully. But that function does not work. Why...

Comment: mycursor.execute(str_truncate) is executed then commits (beacuse autocommit is set to true) then mycursor.executemany(....) starts and commit another transaction